# System.MissingMethodException after upgrading from EF 6.0 Beta to RC

Tags: c#, entity-framework

what does this mean?

> System.MissingMethodException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233069   Message=Method not found:
>   'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.StructuralTypeConfiguration`1.Property(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`12<!0,!!0>>)'.
>   Source=Att.Uds.DataLayerMappings   StackTrace:
>          at Att.Uds.DataLayerMappings.ItemTypeItemConfiguration..ctor()
>          at Att.Uds.DataLayerMappings.UdsContext.OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder
>   modelBuilder) in
>   c:\TFS\ATS-MSDev\UDS\Dev\Code\Att.Uds.DataLayerMappings\UdsContext.cs:line
>   163
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.CallOnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder
>   modelBuilder)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModelBuilder()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy2.GetValue(TInput input)   InnerException:

Error happens on this class:

```
namespace Contoso.Fabrikam.DataLayerMappings
{ 
  public abstract class NamedEntityConfiguration<TEntity> : EntityBaseConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity : NamedEntity
  {
    public ConfigurationColumn NameColumn;
    protected new int LastOrdinalPosition
    {
      get
      {
        return (NameColumn.Ordinal);
      }
    }
    public NamedEntityConfiguration() <=== EXCEPTION HERE
    {
      NameColumn = new ConfigurationColumn() { Ordinal = base.LastOrdinalPosition+1, Name = "Name", IsRequired = true, Length = 128 };
      this.Property(t => t.Name)
        .HasColumnName(NameColumn.Name)
        .HasColumnOrder(NameColumn.Ordinal)
        .HasMaxLength(NameColumn.Length);
      if(NameColumn.IsRequired)
      {
        this.Property(t => t.Name).IsRequired();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You can report beta bugs at the [codeplex site](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic)

Comment: It seems like you built against one version but are actually running against a different version where public API has changed. EF is meant to be bin deployed - so you should run against the version that is copied with your application. So, either for some reason you are copying a different version than the one that your project is build against, or EntityFramework.dll is GACed (GAC wins) on your box (which is not recommended) or you don't copy the EF.dll at all and the type loader finds another/wrong version in its search paths and uses it.

Answer (score 7):

The reason why @Saber his answer works is because when you upgrade your project to a higher .NET Version, the project file is not upgraded automatically. For example, if you upgrade from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5 and edit the project file, you might see the following:

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net40\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

You will have to change the reference to **net45** instead of **net40**. When removing the packages, this will produce the same behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

I've encountered same error.
It worked for me:

1. Uninstall-Package EntityFramework in Package Manager Console
2. Delete EntityFramework folder from 'packages' folder
3. Install-Package EntityFramework in Package Manager Console

Comment: These steps worked for me--thanks. In my case the trigger for this problem was upgrading from .NET 4.0 to 4.5, having EF v6.1.2 installed. By following these steps, EF ended up being upgraded to v6.1.3. Whether it was the cleaning-house aspect or the EF minor revision upgrade aspect that solved it, I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove the EntityFramework.dll from this folder:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\EntityFramework