# Entity Framework method not found; version issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on a system built by another developer. When I run the project I get the following error at run time. Is this an Entity Framework method? Is it from a specific version? I'm not sure how to track down the source of this error.

*System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration`1.ToTable(System.String)'.*

Comment: You might have a version mismatch between what .NET version your proejct targets and what version of EF is targeted, try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29782288/84206

Answer (score 20):

What I have seen happen in the past, is different projects in the solution referencing different versions of EF. I would go through each project, and make sure they reference the same version of EF.

Or simply right click on

**Solution -> Manage NuGet Packages -> Updates -> Entity Framework**

and this will update all of the projects to latest EF.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>.ToTable(String)` method is new in the Entity Framework 5 which is the first release of EF that is separate from the rest of the .NET Framework.

Your project/solution is probably referencing the Entity Framework built-in to the .NET Framework which would be version 4. Ensure you have the correct EF binaries referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Had to restart Visual Studio in my case.

Comment: The wisdom says: "if it's Microsoft-related, just restart" because Microsoft follow the "ignore it" approach in resolving memory problems.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a similar error message was caused by me updating EF in the solution beyond what was compatible with the MySql server it connected to.  So, even though all the projects were running equal versions, it was never going to work against that server.