# Entity Framework wait timeout when adding non-clustered indexes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is annoying. I created an index migration using EF like this:

```
// Add indexes
modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().HasIndex(m => new { m.Reference, m.Type, m.Status, m.DateCreated }).HasName("IX_MessageSearch");
modelBuilder.Entity<Email>().HasIndex(m => new { m.DateCreated, m.Subject, m.To }).HasName("IX_EmailSearch");
```

I tried to run `update-database`, but I kept getting a wait timeout error.

I tried a couple of fixes (changing the Tools > Options > Designer timeout to 900 and making sure there was a tick in the override connection strings) but that didn't work.

So I added:

```
Database.CommandTimeout = 900;
```

And I still got the error. It looks like it ignored it, because the error would happen within 60s.

So I thought I would comment out my migration `Up` method actions:

```
public override void Up()
{
    //CreateIndex("dbo.Emails", new[] { "DateCreated", "Subject", "To" }, name: "IX_EmailSearch");
    //CreateIndex("dbo.Messages", new[] { "Reference", "Type", "Status", "DateCreated" }, name: "IX_MessageSearch");
}
```

And manually create the indexes using SQL Server Management Studio. There are over 100k records in each table, which is why it was timing out I guess.

Anyway, the manual creation worked and then I invoked `update-database` to get the migrations up to date.

But when I try to use my API to get a list of Emails (or Messages) I get this error:

> Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.IndexConfiguration System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration`1.HasIndex(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1>)'.

Does anyone know why? I am using EF 6.2.

Comment: Please, see if this link help you. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493786/entity-framework-method-not-found-version-issue`