# .NET 4.0 and EF 6.1.3 versus .NET 4.6.1 and EF 6.2

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework

This related to a Windows Forms project and I am using Visual Studio 2012. The programming language is C#.

I created a project with .NET 4.0 and EF 6.1.3. The project was stable and worked properly. I was told I had to upgrade to .NET 4.6.1. NuGet said I had to upgrade EF to 6.2.0. I am now dealing with the following error:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.Nullable`1)'.

When I rollback to .NET 4.0 and EF 6.1.3, then the project works as it originally did.

What do I need to do to get my project to work in .NET 4.6.1 with EF 6.2.0?

Please let me know if you have any question or concerns.

Comment: How about .NET 4.6.1 with EF6.1.3? I'm successfully using this combination for a long time w/o issues.

Comment: As Ivan mentioned - there's no reason EF6.1.3 shouldn't work with .NET 4.6.1. Sounds like it might be a project reference issue - possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881575/system-missingmethodexception-after-upgrading-from-ef-6-0-beta-to-rc

Comment: I have tried to use .NET 4.6.1 with EF 6.1.3. I get the same error as described.

Comment: Have you checked your project references, per the linked question?

Comment: Where do I edit the project file? where is it located?

Comment: From what I can see in the references for the two files, both are pointed toward "..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\"

Comment: Does anyone have any other recommendations?